# Installing additional driver for Networked Printer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, printing

I'm pretty new to the whole server thing and am using some VM's at home to mess around. Essentially I have installed a printer which is connected into my router and has a static IP. I've installed the printer on my 2008 R2 (64bit) VM and created a script to install the printer for my XP and Windows 7 Client VM's (32bit) - but they can't install because there is no driver!

So I understand I need to use the Additional drivers option under the Sharing tab on the Printer. Do I add the 2008 R2 32bit driver? Do I add the Windows 7 32bit driver? Since I have XP and 7 I don't know which x86 driver to add?

Strangely - and maybe this is case - I have downloaded a printer driver for 2008R2 64 bit - and extracted it - added a printer using the 64 driver on my server VM, then added the additional driver for my 32bit version - and still my XP and 7 Clients can use the driver? Do the Server drivers (2003 and 2008) contain all OS' drivers or does it not matter which OS platform you get for the driver, just any 32bit driver will do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I add the 2008 R2 32bit driver?

There's no such thing.

> Do I add the Windows 7 32bit driver? Since I have XP and 7 I don't know which x86 driver to add?

Usually the print drivers aren't version specific. x86 Win 7 drivers typically work fine for XP clients.

> Strangely - and maybe this is case - I have downloaded a printer driver for 2008R2 64 bit - and extracted it - added a printer using the 64 driver on my server VM, then added the additional driver for my 32bit version - and still my XP and 7 Clients can use the driver? Do the Server drivers (2003 and 2008) contain all OS' drivers or does it not matter which OS platform you get for the driver, just any 32bit driver will do?

This is normal, though typically x86 Server 2008 or 2003 drivers are a little more outdated than x86 W7 drivers for the same model.

Comment: Hi there - so if I Downloaded the 2008R2 drivers from the internet - and it contained a x64 and x86 driver - I add them both through additional - 7 and XP clients would work? How is that exactly :) I mean, do the drivers just work for all OS' or do the server drivers contain all OS driver compatability?

Comment: Most print drivers are designed to work across all modern OSes. As an aside, there is no 32-bit 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Server drivers do not come with drivers for other OSs, but for just about any printer, you can download the drivers for most OSs. The manufacturer's website should list drivers for XP 64 and 32 bit, Win7 64 and 32 bit, etc. Win 7 drivers should work for 2008, Vista drivers for 2003. Download the ones you need and install them under "additional drivers". Then, things should work when you install the printer as a Networked Printer on a client.

One problem with 2008 server: you will need to make sure that the printer names match **exactly** for all OSs. Hence "HP LaserJet 4" is **not** the same as "HP Laserjet 4 PCL". That can be a big problem, but there are 2 ways to fix it. One is to use a universal driver (if your printer has one), as that should have the same name in all cases. Failing that, you can edit the .INF files to match names.

Comment: `Server drivers do not come with drivers for other OSs` that's a pretty broad assumption. One that's not necessarily accurate.